# How to: Multiple iOS Enterprise Applications inhouse

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, enterprise

I am trying to develop two separate applications for our company using the Enterprise Program.
Regardless of what I've tried, the second app always replaces the first app...

Create iOS Production cert1, download, keychain, upload, Provisioning Profile 1 created.

Repeat iOS Production cert2, download, keychain, upload, Provisioning Profile 2 created.

I am not sure why I have gone wrong. Is there a step I need to take differently?
////
edit:
I have gone back to Apple and created a second app id.. the bundle identifier is the same. I used com.domain.* and org.domain.* for both. It will not allow me to create a third (understandably) ... Will we be limited to two apps total?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  Before I consider where this should be hosted (here or stack overflow), could you edit in how the apps are created? Perhaps you simply need to name them differently in whatever system builds them (Xcode, etc...) If you don't know that, perhaps expand on what steps precicely you under take on "create production cert" since if you are exact, someone could perhaps connect a dot or explain what is happening

Comment: I am using phonegap to build. I know this is not ideal but it's so fluid to use with iOS and Android when both apps are simple data acquisition and must match exactly in both look and feel.

Comment: Phonegap is just a tool. Did you look at figure 5 for the app id in this documentation? http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/getting-started-with-phonegap-in-xcode-for-ios.html  The answer from mahboudz resonates with figure 4 as well.

Comment: What do you mean by replace?

Comment: when I install the second app it shows as loading where the first app was installed and the second app loads up

Answer (score 1):

Are you using two different bundle IDs in Xcode's project target?  That's the string that looks like this:

com.yourcompany.app1
com.yourcompany.app2

or

com.yourcompany.allapss.app1
com.yourcompany.allapss.app2

If I assume that you've done your provisioning profiles correctly, then the reason an app would replace another would be if they had identical bundle IDs.

Comment: I was not offered to set a second bundle ID, when I set the first one I set it up as com.company.* as I thought this would allow us multiple in house apps. That may very well be where I missed a step, how do I add another bundle ID?

Comment: The bundle id for the app is set in the Info.plist in Xcode.  The cert can either be a wildcard (allowing any bundle id you set in Xcode) or can be a specific bundle id, in which case you would need separate certs for different apps.

Comment: Alan's right.  Set the bundle IDs to be different.  The wildcard bundle ID that you used for the provisioning profile should be fine.  Just tell Xcode to have different bundle IDs for each app, and they'll stop overwriting one another.